# Host web app in Tomcat for users in LAN

Tags: tomcat, local-area-network, fedora

I have a web app which is running on Tomcat 7, on Fedora 14. I can access that application in my local pc but how do I make it available to the other users of the LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a Host that defines your local network address/name instead of localhost:

See here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: Could you please some more description